# Running sh script gives command not found for any unix/linux basic commands

Tags: linux, windows, shell, cygwin

I'm running Shell script which has basic commands.

For any command in script I'm getting errors as below:

> line 3548: mv: command not found
>    line 3550: cmd: command not found
>    line 708: mkdir: command not found
>    line 715: cygpath: command not found
>    line 726: mv: command not found
>    line 727: cp: command not found
>    line 731: mv: command not found
>    line 732: cp: command not found
>    line 736: mv: command not found
>    line 737: cp: command not found
>    line 749: expr: command not found
>    line 770: expr: command not found

*NOTE*: I've added c:\cygwin\bin and various other directories under c:\Cygwin\usr like sbin,X11R6,local in my windows system variable PATH. I also tried reinstalling Cygwin with same issue. I'm using Windows 10. I'm running cmd in admin mode and then running bash.

Comment: are you running cygwin using the Cygwin terminal (mintty) ? It seems you are NOT running a bash login shell

Comment: try with full command/exe path for example  c:\cygwin\bin\mv

Comment: What does your cygwin PATH -- not the Windows PATH -- look like?

Comment: BTW, as an aside, well-written scripts don't use `expr`, which is a backwards-incompatibility holdout from the 1970s. POSIX-compliant math uses `$(( ... ))` instead.

Comment: In your script, have you done: `PATH="some value"`? I'd normally say "show your script", but given the line numbers, please don't.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm running bash from windows command prompt and not from Cygwin Terminal, full path will always work but i can't change all preexisting-grandfathered scripts i've for env setup with direct path for each mv/cp/cygpath etc. commands, yes my product has roots in 1980s so expr is part of these scripts unfortunately. Yes in my script i did set PATH = but still same result.

Comment: Ohh Also because of very old application i can't use latest versions of Cygwin, i'm using 1.73.1 installation right now.

Answer (score 0):

The first invocation of bash must be a login shell.
If not the enviroment is incorretly set

```
E:\cygwin64>bin\bash.exe
bash: arch: command not found
bash: ARCH: command not found
bash: ARCH: command not found
bash: dircolors: command not found

marco@FG /
```

While the enviroment is correct with a login shell

```
E:\cygwin64>bin\bash.exe -l

marco@FG ~
```

This is the reason why the Mintty / Cygwin Terminal shortcut use the "-"

```
$ mintty --help
Usage: mintty [OPTION]... [ PROGRAM [ARG]... | - ]

Start a new terminal session running the specified program or the user's shell.
If a dash is given instead of a program, invoke the shell as a login shell.
...
```